# Error [BC30205] End of statement expected

Tags: vba

```
public Function NumberOfSundays(byval dFrom as object,byval dTo  as object) 

   While dFrom <= dTo Begin
      If datepart(dw, dFrom) = 1 then
           return dFrom
      Set dFrom = DateAdd(d, 1, dFrom)
else

Set dFrom = DateAdd(d, 1, dFrom)

End if

end while
end function
```

I am using the above code to return Sunday date, but getting the following error

> There is an error in line 3 of custom code: [BC30205] End of statement expected.

Answer (score 0):

- `Begin` is an unknown command
- VBA does not have a `Return` statement.
- `DateAdd` returns a `Date`, not an object, and therefore you shouldn't `Set` something to its result
- Assuming VBA did have a `Return` statement, there would be no point in doing something immediately after it as that line would never be reached.
- A `While` statement is ended with a `Wend`, not an `End While`

Comment: Thanks, i did not realise that i was using sql code in VBA and i was keep on correcting it.